# What's the difference between <% and <%:

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I couldn't find anything through Google, I suppose the search terms are too much to handle.
The VS built-in help only explains <%, which is just embedded code. There is no mention of <%:

**EDIT:**
My book says, that the only difference is that <%: returns a MvcHtmlString. Why do we need an extra symbol for <%: just to return something?

**EDIT2:**
An example:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("xxx", "xxx"); %>
```

Nothing is returned, that's why we have to say <%, because it would htmlencode? But what if I render something in .RenderAction() that needs to be htmlencoded too? Or does that not make sense?

Thanks for any help! It would really help me to understand asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in other answers, it is for Html encoding.  [Here's a blog entry explaining](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Using `<%:` you are already tell the page to HtmlEncode what is inside the <%: %> tags. and it was presented in .Net 4.

**EDIT:** Yes, MvcHtmlString is already HtmlEncoded.

**P.S:** If you want (sometimes) not to encode text as HTML stick with the old ones but you have to know that if that data was provided by users it is considered a security threat which could be used as an exploit to impose XSS attacks against your web site/application.

Answer (score 2):

Both are used to render text on the view, however when you use <%: , the text is automatically HTMLEncoded.